# Concatenar Linhas com o mesmo Usuário

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

Tenho a Seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT e.id_taxe, u.nm_user, dt_taxe, SUM(e.vl_taxe) as vl_taxe
FROM taxe as e 
INNER JOIN user as u ON u.id_user = e.id_user 
WHERE id_enterprise = 86 AND (dt_taxe BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31') 
AND lg_cancel = 0 GROUP BY e.dt_taxe, e.id_user ORDER BY e.id_user,e.dt_taxe
```

Que me retorna :

```
id_taxe     nm_user   dt_taxe      vl_taxe
728         Maria     2017-01-01   17091.07048034668
727         Maria     2017-02-01   14091.07048034668
721         Maria     2017-03-01   1021.07048034668
731         Pedro     2017-01-01   16353.569854736328
732         Pedro     2017-02-01   6353.56231239
```

Como posso concatenar os campos do mesmo usuário na mesma linha, para ter o seguinte resultado:

```
id_taxe     nm_user   dt_taxe      vl_taxe
728         Maria     2017-01-01   17091.07048034668 , 
                      2017-02-01   14091.07048034668,
                      2017-03-01   1021.07048034668
731         Pedro     2017-01-01   16353.569854736328,
                      2017-02-01   6353.56231239
```

Comment: Bia, conceitualmente você possui 3 registros com id_taxe distintos, Perceba que o seu id_taxe no exemplo ficou fixo em 728, sendo que a Maria possui outros (727 e 721)

Comment: @NajibElAlam na verdade o id não me importa, somente a data e o valor

Answer (score -1):

**bom, considerando a seguinte estrutura**

```
CREATE TABLE user
    (`id_user` int, `nome` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO user
    (`id_user`, `nome`)
VALUES
    (1, 'maria')
;

INSERT INTO user
    (`id_user`, `nome`)
VALUES
    (2, 'pedro')
;


**tabela de taxas** 
CREATE TABLE taxe
    (`id_user` int, `id_taxe` int, `data` varchar(11), `taxe` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO taxe
   (`id_user`, `id_taxe`, `data`, `taxe`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-01-01', '17091.070')
;

INSERT INTO taxe
   (`id_user`, `id_taxe`, `data`,`taxe`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, '2017-02-01', '121222.70')
;

INSERT INTO taxe
   (`id_user`, `id_taxe`, `data`,`taxe`)
VALUES
    (1, 3, ' 2017-03-01', '999922.70')
;


INSERT INTO taxe
   (`id_user`, `id_taxe`, `data`, `taxe`)
VALUES
    (2, 4, '2017-01-01', '16353.564')
;

INSERT INTO taxe
   (`id_user`, `id_taxe`, `data`,`taxe`)
VALUES
    (2, 5, '2017-02-01', '6353.562')
;
```

**seria mais ou menos assim sua consulta, usando group_concat **

```
select u.id_user, group_concat(
DISTINCT u.nome
    ORDER BY u.nome DESC SEPARATOR ' '
) as nome, 

group_concat(
  DISTINCT t.data
ORDER BY t.data DESC SEPARATOR ',') as data, 

group_concat(
  DISTINCT t.taxe
ORDER BY t.taxe DESC SEPARATOR ',') as taxes 

from user u
inner join taxe t
on t.id_user = u.id_user
group by u.id_user;
```

**com o resultado**

```
id_user nome    data    taxes
1   maria   2017-02-01,2017-01-01, 2017-03-01   999922.70,17091.070,121222.70
2   pedro   2017-02-01,2017-01-01   6353.562,16353.564
```

espero ter ajudado. Abraço :=)

segue link de execução no [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af97a6/1/0)